# What are some languages with inflected future tense?

Tags: tense

I recently realized that English has no inflected future tense. I would like to study a language that has an inflected future tense.

What options are available?

Comment: There are really lots of them; classical Latin and modern Romance languages are easily accessible candidates.

Comment: Also Greek, Sanskrit ...

Comment: But modern Romance languages rarely use the future tense, preferring constuctions (usually with reflexes of Latin _ire_ 'go', like _On va voir_ or _Vamos a ver_).

Comment: @jlawler I'm not sure I'd say "rarely", but it's certainly less common in the spoken language. It "feels" different, more casual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty to choose from!
[Just take a look at this map.](http://wals.info/feature/67A#2/25.5/148.2)

Here are a few examples from that page:

- Banjalang (also known as Bundjalung, and several other spellings)
- Arabic
- Zulu
- Spanish

Comment: Classical Arabic has aspect (perfect/imperfect), not tense (past/future) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_verbs#Tense

Comment: @ba That's possible. But that map is referring to Egyptian Arabic, and cites Eisele 1999 as its source. It might be worth noting that Tunisian Arabic does not have inflectional future according to that site.

Comment: Does Esperanto have inflected future tense? It's not on that map

Comment: Russian has inflected future tense (_сделаю/сделаешь_) but the map claims it does not

Comment: @J-mster Russian is not on that map because *сделаю/сделаешь* is usually analysed as present tense, perfective aspect, just like the situation with Classical Arabic. Of course, it's used to refer to future happenings, but grammatically it's present.

Comment: @safebookverified I don't know, did you look it up?

Comment: It seems like it does

Comment: That's pretty silly: it's claiming that Portuguese has no inflectional future.

Comment: @user21170 - Esperanto has a future tense. Mi amas / mi amis / mi amos = I love / I loved / I'll love. Esperanto even has present, past and future active and passive participles.